# android emulation error (haxm installed)

Tags: android, emulation

I'm new to Android. I was trying to run my first hello world program but I got this error message:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware >acceleration!
>   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

I'm using windows 10, my processor is intel and I verified that it supports virtualization. I checked and verified that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
I also checked and verified that Hyper-V is disabled since I read on some forums that it causes problems with virtual devices.
I have installed Android API 28 and Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) as sdk platforms. For sdk tools I have sdk build-tools, auto API simulator, emulator, sdk platform-tools, sdk tools, and intel x86 Emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) all installed and up to date.

Can anyone help ? I just don't know where's the problem so I can fix it ?

Comment: Please edit question with operating system and version of Android SDK installed.

Comment: @MorrisonChang done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution guys, so I'm posting it for any newbie who's still searching for it.

Windows 10 enforces driver signatures by default. This actually is preventing the emulator accelerator from being installed properly. To solve this issue use the following steps to disable driver signature enforcement.

1. Click the Start Start menu and select Settings.
2. Click Update and Security.
3. Click on Recovery.
4. Click Restart now under Advanced Startup.
5. Click Troubleshoot.
6. Click Advanced options.
7. Click Startup Settings.
8. Click on Restart.
9. On the Startup Settings screen press 7 or F7 to disable driver signature enforcement.

Your computer will restart and you will be able to install non-digitally signed drivers. All you need to do now is to re-install(or update) intel x86 Emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) and enjoy !

If you restart your computer again the driver signature enforcement will be re-enabled.